# What is the syntax used in this function definition of Cardano?

Tags: haskell, cardano

How to interpret [this function](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/9d59676141f9a0210a964191cb5f64f0d68d4d0c/cardano-cli/src/Cardano/CLI/Run/Friendly.hs#L112):

```
friendlyValidityRange
  :: CardanoEra era
  -> (TxValidityLowerBound era, TxValidityUpperBound era)
  -> Aeson.Value
friendlyValidityRange era = \case
  ShelleyTtl ttl -> object ["time to live" .= ttl]
  (lowerBound, upperBound)
    | isLowerBoundSupported || isUpperBoundSupported ->
        object
          [ ...
          ]
    | otherwise -> Null
 where
  isLowerBoundSupported = isJust $ validityLowerBoundSupportedInEra era
  isUpperBoundSupported = isJust $ validityUpperBoundSupportedInEra era
```

I thought the `friendlyValidityRange` function utilize the *partial function* concept, but still failed to understand it.
How can `friendlyValidityRange`'s `era` and `(lowerBound, upperBound)` parameters be passed in such separated way?

I try to mimic it use follow demo, still unable to finished it.

```
module Main where

data Age = Child | Adult

-- Function that accept two agrs: Age, (weightMin, weightMax) , and return health description string
weightAnalyse :: Age -> (Int, Int) -> String
weightAnalyse age = \case
    Child    ->  ?  -- how to comsume the (min, max) tuple
    Adult    ->  ? 
    
main :: IO ()
main = do
  weightAnalyse Child (30, 60)
  weightAnalyse Adult (60, 130)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing [Pattern Synonyms](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/pattern_synonyms.html). Take a look at [line 105](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/9d59676141f9a0210a964191cb5f64f0d68d4d0c/cardano-cli/src/Cardano/CLI/Run/Friendly.hs#L112)

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}

pattern ShelleyTtl
  :: SlotNo -> (TxValidityLowerBound era, TxValidityUpperBound era)
pattern ShelleyTtl ttl <-
  ( TxValidityNoLowerBound
  , TxValidityUpperBound ValidityUpperBoundInShelleyEra ttl
  )
```

This says that a tuple where the first component is `TxValidityNoLowerBound` and the second component is `TxValidityUpperBound ValidityUpperBoundInShelleyEra ttl` can be used as the pattern `ShelleyTtl ttl` with `ttl` bound to the correct value.

So `ShelleyTtl ttl` in

```
friendlyValidityRange era = \case
  ShelleyTtl ttl -> object ["time to live" .= ttl]
```

matches a particular type of tuple!

Your `weightAnalyse` does not really match the example you are referencing but would go along the lines of:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase, PatternSynonyms  #-}

data Age = Child String | Adult

pattern ChildPattern x <- (_, Child x)

weightAnalyse :: Int -> (Int, Age) -> String
weightAnalyse id = \case
  ChildPattern x -> x
  (a, age) -> "other"
-- The parameter id is unused and could be removed but is kept
-- to match the original version of the function.

--  *> weightAnalyse 1 (30, Child "foo")
-- "foo"
--  *> weightAnalyse 2 (60, Adult)
-- "other"
```

Comment: A rather dubious use of pattern synonyms IMO. Why did they use tuples in the first place, instead of a more suitable ADT?

Comment: Sorry for late response. 
Thanks for your answer and example.  
It is a bit hard to  the power of `PatternSynonyms`. It seem we can live without it as well. I need to spend more time to study on it.